# what does nominal numbers of electrical machines mean

Tags: electric-machine, device-characteristics

I got confused about rated numbers of generators and motors like rated voltage and rated power .

I know nominal numbers of electrical machines are numbers which the machine is designed to operate but for example I don't know what the nominal power of a generator is , is it the provided electrical power or required power to operate or what ?

To be specific , in dc generators and motors , what do these factors represent :

- Voltage
- Power
- Rotational speed

thanks

Comment: It's one or the other but without a more detailed inspection of its documents, it's hard to say.

Comment: Generally generator should generate power , don’t you think?

Comment: I would expect a generator to transform mechanical power into electrical power to be more precise.

Comment: @LarsHankeln unless it was some other type like fission reactor or thermal pile or geothermal or solar power generating station

Comment: @andy aka Tanks for reminding me to be specific , I edited my post

Comment: If it's in horsepower it's input power. If it's in kW it's either output power or the datasheet is aimed at users of the SI system.

Comment: @tony stewart sunnyskyguy ee75 I know what generator mean , I got confused about the meaning of the characteristics like nominal power in motor , does it mean the mechanical power or the power that transformed from electricitical form to mechanical form

Comment: Something like 750W/Hp look it up

Comment: Then search motor/generator losses

Comment: @AlirezaOe I reminded you that to get an answer, you would need to describe your study documents in more details. I didn't remind you to expand your question whilst still not providing images of sections of the study documents you are reading.

Comment: i think that "nominal" is loosely synonymous with "sucessful" ... nominal power of a generator is power that will be generated successfuly if conditions are within design specification ... it can also mean "named" or "specified", which would be the designer's declaration that the generator will produce a certain power level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nominal means almost the same thing as rated. However ratings generally have tolerances and limitations attached to them. Motor have a nominal speed and voltage. The primary ratings will pertain to that same speed and voltage. The nominal power rating for a motor is the mechanical output power that it can safely produce at that speed and voltage. The mechanical output power will be stated is either horsepower or kilowatts depending on the standards applied.

The motor may be able to operate at other speeds and voltages and have specifications stating what power is safe for those speeds and voltages. Operating under those conditions may be considered as operating within the motor's ratings even though they are not the nominal operating conditions.

Generator ratings are similar to motor ratings. The nominal power would be the rated output electrical power stated in watts.

The nominal power and the power stated in the primary ratings is the output mechanical power for motors and electrical power for generators. A generator or motor is likely to have an efficiency rating. The input power may be left to be determined using the efficiency and output power ratings.

AC generators have both a maximum output power and a maximum output current or minimum power factor rating. For safe operation, neither the maximum power nor the maximum current can be exceeded.